# The callback of delegator factory returns null

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework, ioc-container, laminas

I would like to wrap an existing service with another one, so, I've found that there is a delegator factory mechanism https://docs.mezzio.dev/mezzio/v3/features/container/delegator-factories/

The service is very simple and I've mostly copy-pasted the example in documentation.

Even without simplification the service looks something like this

```php
class MoneyService {
    public function __constructor(LoggerService $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}
```

To check that delegator factory works I've created it like this. Just to be sure that the real service was built correctly.

```php
class MoneyServiceDelegatorFactory
{

    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, string $name, callable $callback)
    {
        var_dump($name, $callback());
        die;
    }
}
```

And finally I wire it with configureation

```
'dependencies' => [
    'delegators' => [
        MoneyService::class => [
            MoneyServiceDelegatorFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
],
```

If I try to check if the container has the MoneyService instance then it is true - `$container->has(MoneyService::class) === true`.

So, in the delegator factory I expect the result of `$callback()` to be an instance of a MoneyService class. But instead I get null.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what was wrong. I use PHP-DI but in this case I have add a factory which returns an instance of MoneyService. After that, in the next factories, it will be available as a result of `$callback()`